# How to prevent "datas delays" in Serial Communication (C# form <-> Arduino)

Tags: c#, forms, arduino, serial-port

The code i have works, but i want to make sure it's robust, as i remember writing similar code in the past (with python) and noticing that i was receiving datas that would be 3 or 4 minutes old and would get even older with time. 
I guess this has to do with the serial buffer, and that i should "clear it" from time to time, what is the best practice for this ?

C# form code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialTest1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SerialPort ArduinoSerial;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
            MyTimer.Interval = (1000); // 1 sec
            MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(SerialTimer_Tick);
            MyTimer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Form1_Loading....");
            OpenSerialPort();
        }
        private void OpenSerialPort() // creating serial communication object
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OpenSerialPort: opening port.....");
                ArduinoSerial = new SerialPort("COM7", 115200);//Set board COM
                ArduinoSerial.Open();
                ArduinoSerial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(dataReceived);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OpenSerialPort: Can not find port");
            }
        }

        // write to arduino and restart Serial com if error like cable disconnected and reconnected
        private void writeToArduino() 
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"writeToArduino: writing msg to arduino");
                ArduinoSerial.WriteLine("hello from pc");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("writeToArduino: Serial Error");
                //MessageBox.Show("Serial Error: " + ex.ToString(), "ERROR");
                if (!ArduinoSerial.IsOpen)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("writeToArduino: ArduinoSerial is close, opening it...");
                    OpenSerialPort();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SerialTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // will write to arduino at each timer tick
        {
            writeToArduino();
        }

        private void dataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // receiving datas from arduino
        {
            string SerialLine = ArduinoSerial.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"dataReceived: Got serial line for arduino: {SerialLine}");
        }
    }
}
```

Arduino code:

```
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <Time.h>

//WINDOWS COMMUNICATION
String receivedString;

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(void) {
    static time_t lastMsg = 0;
    static int counter = 1;
    if (now() - lastMsg > 1) {
        lastMsg = now();
        Serial.print("msg ");
        Serial.print(counter);
        Serial.println("Hello from arduino");
        counter++;
    }
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        receivedString = Serial.readString();
        Serial.println(receivedString);
    }
    delay(5);
}
```

Comment: Considering all your messages are the same how do you know they are old?   Also, if you are going to use such a high baud rate particularly full duplex, you should be using some form of flow control, preferably DTR+DSR+RTS+CTS

Comment: Are you experiencing problems with your current code? or you are just afraid something that happened in the past with a completely different code might happen again... How often is your `SerialTimer_Tick` function being called? You cannot expect the Arduino to keep up the pace if you send data from your computer at maximum speed (without any delay) continuously. I don't think you should need any kind of flow control at that baud rate if your timings make sense on both sides (send and wait listening for an answer a reasonable period of time).

Comment: I think you are timing out because the serial ports are not configured properly.  Make sure you turn off hand shaking on both c# and Arduino (hardware and software), and set port to 8 bit no parity.

Comment: @ MickyD: Messages are not all the same as the arduino sends a counter value with each message. My baud rate is arbitrary, i have no idea what DTR+DSR+RTS+CTS so i'm going to look into it, thanks.  @Marcos G: My code runs fine indeed, but i am worried if some part of it could be improved or are the best practices, my timer ticks every second.Cheers. @ jdweng: i don't know how to set a port parity or set its definition to 8 bits so i will look into it, thank you.

Comment: I prefer using `ReadExisting` over `ReadLine`, as `ReadLine` is blocking your thread until it receives a new line character.  `ReadExisting` returns the contents of the stream and internal buffer of the SerialPort object as a string. This method does not use a time-out.  So your thread won't be blocked and you'll be able to immediately get all the data in the buffer.  However, if you go with this method you'll have to build your own string until you see a new line character.

Comment: *"I guess this has to do with the serial buffer, and that i should "clear it" from time to time, what is the best practice for this ?"* -- Normally that method is the application issuing reads.  For a reference point, I've seen latency measurements for the serial terminal on Linux.  For a generic kernel, the data could take between 1 to 10 milliseconds after arriving at the UART before the C application got the data.  With an optimized kernel the latency was reduced to 0.10 msec, better than an order of magnitude.  Note that blocking **read()** was used for system efficiency.

Comment: *"datas [sic] that would be 3 or 4 minutes old"* -- To avoid rotting (i.e. buffered but unread) data, I've treated messages from a serial terminal as an event.  A dedicated thread would almost always have a **read()** pending (using blocking mode of course).  IOW this thread would be blocked waiting for data when it's not handing off the received message to the processing thread.  BTW "data" is already plural.